How to properly filter query in flask with form data?
This code doesn`t work:
@app.route('/add_hero',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_news():
    form = HeroesForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        db_sess = db_session.create_session()
        clas = db_sess.query(Classes).filter(Classes.name == form.clas.data).first() # returns None
        race = db_sess.query(Races).filter(Races.name == form.race.data).first() # returns None
        hero = Hero(name=form.name.data, class_id=clas.id, race_id=race.id)
        current_user.heroes.append(hero)
        db_sess.merge(current_user)
        db_sess.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template('heroes_form.html', title='Adding hero',
                           form=form)

But if i do this, clas and race variables return instances instead of None:
@app.route('/add_hero',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_news():
    form = HeroesForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        db_sess = db_session.create_session()
        clas = db_sess.query(Classes).filter(Classes.name == 'Orc').first() # returns instance
        race = db_sess.query(Races).filter(Races.name == 'Wizard').first() # returns instance
        hero = Hero(name=form.name.data, class_id=clas.id, race_id=race.id)
        current_user.heroes.append(hero)
        db_sess.merge(current_user)
        db_sess.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template('heroes_form.html', title='Adding hero',
                           form=form)

form.clas.data and form.race.data type is str, i dont understand why it doesn`t work.

If you do print(repr(form.clas.data)) and print(repr(form.race.data)), what is the output?
